# I can't download anything and I can't watch videos

Tags: downloads

Two days ago I tried to download skype and it says an error occurred it says

```
 end of central directory signature not found  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

zipinfo: 
 cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/maria/Downloads/SkypeSetup-aoc-jd.exe
```

or

```
/home/maria/Downloads/SkypeSetup-aoc-jd.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/maria/Downloads/SkypeSetup-aoc-jd.exe.ZIP
```

pe...  this happens whenever I try to download anything like games and also i can't watch videoss it's looking for plug ins but it doesn't find them i hate this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is all mentioned about .exe files and not .deb 

Answer (score 1):

You can install skype here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

For watching videos you can install any player.
for example to install vlc media player you can type

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

.exe is the Windows programs extension. You should download the linux (Ubuntu) version of them.

Try to use the Ubuntu Software Center to install software.

Comment: Here you can download skype for linux:
http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
Choose you're distribution of ubuntu